# Should I use new() or deployed() in Truffle unit tests?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

What's the difference in using `new()` or `deployed()` when creating a contract instance to use in Truffle unit tests? Should I use

```
// VERSION A
it("should work", async () => {
  let instance = await MyContract.deployed();
  :
});
```

or

```
// VERSION B
it("should work", async () => {
  let instance = await MyContract.new();
  :
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`deployed` behaves like a singleton. It will look if there is already an instance of the contract deployed to the blockchain via `deployer.deploy`. The information about which contract has which address on which network is stored in the build folder. `new` will always create a new instance.

It depends on your testcase, but I prefer not using `deployed` in unit tests in order to avoid side-effects and better isolate the unit tests.

Some unit tests will require instantiating multiple instances of a smart contract and deploying each of them. In this case, `new` is the only option as `deployed` simply retrieves the same already-deployed contract each time.