# how is it different .deployed() and .new() ??

Tags: truffle-deployment

When I try to test my contract in truffle test javascript, how is it different to create new instant for my contract by `instant = await myContract.deployed()` and `instant = await myContract.new()`? is it same? 
It seems like I have to use `deployed` in side beforeEach function as follows,

```
  beforeEach('for each test...', async function() {
    instant = await myContract.deployed();
  });
```

every time,to generate new instant then I have to use `new()`, If I just want to use the same instant in my each unit tests, then I have to use `deployed()`? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: seems there's a duplicate question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/should-i-use-new-or-deployed-in-truffle-unit-tests

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right.

Truffle test's `deployed` and `new` are from truffle-contract. If you look at the [doc](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#usage):

> deployed(): Create an instance of MyContract that represents the
> default address managed by MyContract.

> new(): Deploy a new version of this contract to the network, getting an instance > of MyContract that represents the newly deployed instance.

AFAIK, when you run `truffle test`, initially it will go through your migration script, and migrate new contracts onto the node you have specified in `truffle.js`. When you get a instance from `deployed()`, you are actually getting a javascript instance from one of these initially deployed contracts.

On the other hand, when you get a instance from `new()`, it will newly deploy the contract onto the network, and return the corresponding javascript instance.

So, if your contract has states, and the results of tests are dependent on the sequence they are run, then you'll need to use `new()` in beforeEach to get a clean room environment for individual tests.

Note that if you use `contract()` function, then [before each contract() function is run, your contracts are redeployed to the running Ethereum client so the tests within it run with a clean contract state.](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests#use-contract-instead-of-describe-)